# Does GCC protect programmer from multiple including of C's library headers?

Tags: c, include, header

Is there a guarantee that each library header looks something like that?

```
#ifndef STDIO_H
#define STDIO_H
/* contents here... */
#endif
```

Can you please refer me to a source?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking whether the standard C headers can be multiply included, you should ask exactly that. The headers are certainly not required to have guards. Sometimes they don't, especially if the header only includes another file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, GCC does not protect you from a library not using include guards like you described - that is up to the library in question. (And not part of GCC.)

All prominent C standard libraries (glibc, newlibc, ulibc) do guard their includes correctly. (As they are widely used, such a blatant problem would be quickly discovered.)

**Edit:** After your second comment, your question makes more sense now. Quoting from ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99), chapter 7.1.2 Standard Headers, paragraph 4, first sentence:

> Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included more than once in
>   a given scope, with no effect different from being included only once, except that the
>   effect of including <assert.h> depends on the definition of NDEBUG (see 7.2).

That means, if any Standard C library you come across gives you trouble, it's broken.

Comment: Well, *which* one? ;-) While not relevant to your answer (since none of the better-known C libraries around will make any problems in this area), you asked for reference to "a source", and that could only be the source of a *specific* C standard library. You know, while there is a standard those libraries must adhere to (ISO/IEC 9989), there are multiple *implementations* of that standard around...

Comment: I know. What I wanted to know is what the standard said about that. By which I mean ANSI C. It was a mistake talking about GCC, I should have said ANSI C instead.

Answer (score 7):

The C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:TC3) specifically states:

> Standard headers may be included in
>   any order; each may be included more
>   than once in a given scope, with no
>   effect different from being included
>   only once, except that the effect of
>   including `<assert.h>` depends on the
>   definition of NDEBUG (see 7.2).

Point 4 in section 7.1.2

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Standard certainly specifies that standard library headers can be #included more than once. It doesn't specify what the mechanism to avoid multiple definitions must be though. I excpect the C standard (which I have not got) says something similar. But why are you concerned about this?

Comment: Because I have the files `pass1.h' and `pass1.c' and in pass1.c there is #include <stdio.h> and also in pass1.h.
I know I can just remove #include <stdio.h> from pass1.c because it is already included in pass1.h but I wondered if something can break if I don't.

Comment: No, nothing will break - you can include the file as often as you like.

Answer (score 0):

There are **autoconf** scripts written to introduce a **protection against multiple inclusion of header files** for source bases. I am sure this would be done for the Standard C Library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most relevant section I could find in the [most recent draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 6.10.2 6 - A #include preprocessing directive may appear in a source file that has been read because of a #include directive in another file, up to an implementation-defined
>   nesting limit (see 5.2.4.1).

Section 5.2.4.1 then enumerates the minimum required values for various environmental limits; for nested file inclusion, it's 15.

*How* this is accomplished is left up to the individual implementation; the standard does not mandate the use of #include guards, although it's reasonable to assume that's how most implementations do it.

Comment: that is not a relevant section at all. That has to do with *nested* includes, *not* redundant includes.